# R matrix structure - manipulation issue

Tags: r, matrix, vector, stream, dataframe

I'm trying to resolve **two** main issues on an **R** program.

First I need to create a kind-of matrix structure to store for different individuals (rows) the values of different variables (columns).

The main problem is that in each pair row-column I need to have a vector of observations in the form of a time-series. Because the time series in each different variable aren't sampled at sequential times the different time series aren't regular.

I'm thinking of using the **rownames** and **colnames** as keys for accessing the items in the matrix.

Don't know if this is the best structure for what I need. Was using dataframes but had the suggestion to move to matrix because it should store a bit of big amounts of data (datastream).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store individual time series in a list, say `l`, and set `dim` attribute on it. You can set `dimnames` (i.e. row names and column names) too. With that you can use it almost as if it is a matrix/data.frame

```
# Generate length 15 vectors for 10 subjects
l <- replicate(10, list(rnorm(15)))
dim(l) <- c(5, 2)
dimnames(l) <- list(subject=1:5, variable=c("a", "b"))
l
##        variable
## subject a          b         
##       1 Numeric,15 Numeric,15
##       2 Numeric,15 Numeric,15
##       3 Numeric,15 Numeric,15
##       4 Numeric,15 Numeric,15
##       5 Numeric,15 Numeric,15
```

Now you can:

```
l[[1,1]]    # time series for subject 1, var 1
##  [1] -0.02425  0.88986  0.36260 -1.78774 -1.48874 -1.46750  0.38329
##  [8]  0.18573 -1.65675  0.59374  0.81669  1.06867 -1.71847  0.81889
## [15]  0.10796
```

or

```
l[[2, "b"]] # time series for subject 2, var "b"
##  [1]  0.45616 -0.67563 -1.42116 -0.42621  0.51648  0.35147  0.68243
##  [8]  1.17581 -0.16696  0.77492 -1.76446  1.50580  0.06075  0.37734
## [15] -0.92797
```

etc...

Comment: +1 I've accidentally created matrices containing lists before, but when intentionally creating them, I never thought to set `dim` on an existing list.

Comment: Note that `l[[2, 'b']]` refers to variable `b` for the second _row_. In @Michal's example this is also the subject 2, but if subjects are out of order, or if some are missing, this may not be the case. Of course for this example, `l[['2', 'b']]` would subset `l` to variable `b` and the row with name '2'.