# r matrix online structure taking too long

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, data-stream

This question comes in the sequence of a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362300/r-matrix-structure-manipulation-issue) one I asked this week.

But generally my problem goes as follows:

- I have a **datastream** of records entering in **R** via a socket and I want to do some analyses.

They come sequentially like this:

1. individual 1  |  1   |  2   |   timestamp 1
2. individual 2  |  4   | 10   |   timestamp 2
3. individual 1  |  2   |  4   |   timestamp 3

I need to create a structure to maintain those records. The main idea is discussed in the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362300/r-matrix-structure-manipulation-issue) question but generally I've created a structure that looks like:

```
                     *var1*     *var2*             *timestamp*
- individual 1   | [1,2,3] |  [2,4,6]   | [timestamp1, timestamp3...]
- individual 2   | [4,7,8] | [10,11,12] | [timestamp2, ...]
```

**IMPORTANT - this structure is created and enlarged at runtime. I think this is not the best choice as it takes too long creating. The main structure is a *matrix* and inside each pair individual variable I have *lists* of records.**

3. The individuals are on great number and vary a lot over time. So without going through some records I don't have enough information to make a good analyse. Thinking about creating some king of cache at run time on R by saving the records of individuals to disk.
4. My full database has an amount of approximately 100 GB. I want to analyse it mainly by seasonal blocks within each individual (dependent on the timestamp variable).
5. The creation of my structure takes too long as I enlarge the amount of records I'm collecting.
6. The idea of using a matrix of data with lists inside each pair individual - variable was adapted from using a three dimensional matrix because I don't have observations at the same timestamps. Don't know if it was a good idea.

If anyone has any idea on this matter I would appreciate it.

Comment: where do you datastream come for ? Do you have to analyse online ? Why not storing it into a SQLite DB for instance ?

Comment: My datastream comes from a server which generates records at runtime. The problem with a database would be the writing and reading times.